# wp_nav_menu(); Outside WordPress installation

Tags: plugins, menus

I wanted to use WordPress menu management then show it on outside wordpress installion php file with html but I got this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get_queried_object() on a non-object in .../blog/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php on line 395
```

Here how I do it in on php file with test.php

```
<?php 
$documentroot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include_once($documentroot.'/blog/wp-load.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>

</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
 <div id="main-nav">
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'landingpage-menu' ) ) { /* if menu location 'secondary-menu' exists then use custom menu */ ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'landingpage-menu', 'container' => '', 'depth' => 1 ) ); ?>
<?php } ?>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

is there wrong on how I implement it? or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code and it will really help you a lot

```
<?php
require( '../wp-load.php' );
get_header(newtheme);

echo 'new content outside WordPress';

get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit as how it helps in addition to the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

That should work fine. Likely problems are either the incorrect path[1] at the top or no menu named `landingpage-menu`[2].

[1] For the pathing, try this at the top of your file and see if it's doing what you expect.

```
<?php 
    $documentroot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    echo "documentroot is: " . $documentroot . "<br><br>";

    $filecontents = file_get_contents($documentroot.'/blog/wp-load.php');
    echo $filecontents;
?>
```

[2] For the menus, try this:

```
<h2>Menu Locations</h2>
<pre>
    <?php print_r($menuLocations); ?>
</pre>

<h2>Menus</h2>
<pre>
    <?php print_r($menus); ?>
</pre>
```

It should list out all menus and menu locations.